# Watir and text field inside iframe

Tags: ruby, iframe, watir

I'm trying to setup new text into a text field using Watir. The text field is placed inside iframe.

```
<div id="div_popup_layer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div id="id_Login" class="ui-draggable" style="position:absolute;left:372.5px;top:279px;width:501px;height:274px;z-index:15">
<table id="popup_cont_id_Login" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" topmargine="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle">
<iframe id="frame_id_Login" height="274px" frameborder="0" width="501px" allowtransparency="true" src="/sws.login/gnb/loginView.sws?basedURL=undefined&popupid=id_Login" tagtype="popup_iframe" name="frame_id_Login">
```

The text field has next Xpath:

```
//*[@id="IDUserId"]
```

Or CSS Path:

```
html body#POPUP_BODY table#loginBackground tbody tr td form#loginForm table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td div#userIDBlock table tbody tr td table tbody tr td#swsText_body_IDUserId_td.sws_text_normal_body div input#IDUserId.sws_text_input
```

And in case of HTML it looks like this:

```
<div><input type="text" value="" maxlength="63" style="width:142px; " class="sws_text_input" name="IDUserId" id="IDUserId" onfocus=" swsText_styleChangedFocus('IDUserId');" autocomplete="off" tagtype="text"></div>
```

I've checked a lot of variants without success. For example:

```
browser.frame(:id => "frame_id_Login").text_field(:name => "IDUserId").set "admin"
```

Returns:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/frame.rb:9:in `locate': unable to locate frame/iframe using {:id=>"frame_id_Login"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException)
```

Could anyone help me with it? I need to put any text into the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@browser.text_field(:id => "IDUserId").set "TEXT"
@browser.text_field(:name => "IDUserId").set "TEXT"
@browser.text_field(:class => "sws_text_input").set "TEXT"
```

Those will all work for a this text field as long as it is not contained in a frame, at which point you will need to identify it.

You only want to use Xpath as a last result, as it is fragile and complicated.  I'm not even sure if CSS works as I've never tried it.

Please check out [Željko's WATIR book](http://watir.com/book/) or [www.watir.com](http://www.watir.com) for basic locator methods.

Comment: Yes, the text field are placed inside a iframe. Unfortunately, I have problem with addressing the iframe too.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe watir has been updated since these answers were posted, but none of these `frame` methods worked for me. I was able to successfully use the `iframe` method, and interact with that just like any other object. Once the iframe object was selected, I could call on DOM elements after the iframe call successfully. Was only able to select the iframe object using its 'id' tag even though it had a 'name' attribute as well..

```
browser.text_field(:id => "handle").exists?
#=> false

browser.iframe(:id => "secureform").text_field(:id => "handle").exists?
#=> true
```

Comment: The locating of [frames vs iframes was changed in version 0.6.5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21538399/1200545). `frame` no longer locates both `frame` and `iframe` elements. `iframe` elements now need to be located using the `iframe` method.

Comment: a pity the lack of backwards compatibility

Answer (score 1):

The working solution is:

```
browser.frame(:index => 1).text_field(:index => 0).set "admin"
```

Now I'm trying to understand why :)

Comment: What about: 
    browser.frame(:index => 1).text_field(:id => "IDUserId").set "admin"     Curious because it just sounds like the iframe you're calling is not the one you think it is (there may be another, or the ID is dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution
browser.frame(:id => "iFrameID").text_field(:id => /TextField/).set "data"

HTH