# Accessing elements from within a iFrame -fails in watir-webdriver 0.6.6 - works fine in 0.6.4

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am trying to select a value in a dropdown which is inside a iFrame.  The frame is nested within a table.
HTML:

```
<html class ="some text"> 
<head>...</head> <body id="htmlBody"> 
 <div class= "modalWindow ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content ModalWindow containsFrame" id="ui-id-2"> 
   <iframe src= "/MyApplicantPortal/Applicant/254471/SelectOrderTemplate?t=1"> 
   #document 
    <html class = "some text" 
     <head id= "Head1"> 
     <body id="htmlBody"> 
     <form method= "post" action="SelectOrderTemplate?t=1" id="form1"> 
      <div class = "ModalContent"> 
       <Table> 
        <td class="label1"> 
         <Select id= "MyselList" </td>
```

My code:

```
element(:select_frame, :frame, :src => MyApplicantPortal\/Applicant\/\d+\/SelectOrderTemplate\?t=1/)
select_list(:template) {select_frame_element.select_list_element(:id => 'MyselList')}
```

Error: 
    `Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException: unable to locate frame using {:src=>/MyApplicantPortal\/Applicant\/\d+\/SelectOrderTemplate\?t=1/, :tag_name=>"frame"}`

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right code? The page-object code is looking for `SelectQuoteTemplate`, yet the exception says it is trying to find `SelectOrderTemplate`.

Comment: APologies. That is a typo. I have edited the html.

Comment: I finally found a root cause of the failure. The Watir-Webdriver causes this to fail. I reverted back to watir-webdriver 0.6.4 and it worked fine. Watir-webdriver 0.6.6 causes the failure. Not sure what has changed between the 2 versions.

Comment: I've just released a new version of the gem that fixes this issue.  You will now hove to use the in_frame method for frames only and the in_iframe method for frames.

Comment: Thank you Cheesy. I will test and let you know.

Comment: @Cheezy The new version of gem fixed the problem. Thank you for this update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watir-webdriver 0.6.5 has changed the way locating frames works.

- Before (ie pre-0.6.5), `browser.frame` located `frame` and `iframe` elements.
- Now, `browser.frame` locates `frame` elements and `browser.iframe` locates `iframe` elements.

You will need to change your frame accessor to match the new rules (when you migrated to 0.6.5 or later). The second parameter needs to change from `:frame` to `:iframe`:

```
element(:select_frame, :iframe, :src => /MyApplicantPortal\/Applicant\/\d+\/SelectOrderTemplate\?t=1/)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of releasing a new version of the page-object gem that addresses this issue.  Should be out in a day or two.